# Titanium: create buttons with text underneath them

Tags: android, ios, titanium

this is for tianium - currently looking at android developement, but any ios particular info is equally welcome!

so i have a titanium app, and i'd like to have buttons in it. Each button is for a different "section" though, so i thought "hey, why not make each section have an icon, and put text under it, so the end result looks really similar to a windows desktop, or, say, an ipad/iphone home screen"

To be clear, what i'd like is a selection of images with some text under them, which is clickable.

Like so!

```
  <img      <img      <img
   img       img       img
   img>      img>      img>
 section1  section2   has a 
                     long name
```

But how do i do this? Adding a "title" to a button just has the text appear beside it, not under it

cheers~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for what is known as a Dashboard View. Unfortunately, there is none for android, only iOS.

Searching the forums a little bit, I found this: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/67631/grid-view-is-possible-or-not#answer-206038

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple buttons. Set the button's background `'@null'`, set a `drawableTop` (this will contain your section image), and set the text of the button. Of course, you can format this Button as you want, add margins, padding, format text, etc.

Here is [one](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/232549/icons.png) of my layouts where i used this technique.

If you want a nice layout for these buttons, use merged linearlayouts, or use a programmed RelativeLayout.

Comment: He's coding in Titanium, not native Java...I think that is what you're referring to